# pushing to pypi via github actions: how to manage changes with no version number update?

Tags: python, github-actions, versioning, pypi

One can use github actions to publish to PyPI everytime there is an updated on the master branch.

For example, one can use: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-python-poetry-package

For good reasons, publication on PyPI will fail if the version number is not updated ("HTTP Error 400: File already exists."). (good reasons explained here: https://pypi.org/help/#file-name-reuse)

Yet, content of the master branch may sometimes be updated in ways that do not justify an update of the version number (e.g. if the github actions, not the software, is updated).

What would be recommended way to handle this, and how can it be implemented ? For example, is it possible to trigger the github action for publishing only if there is a version update ? or only if the source code has been updated ? Or is there a way to ignore the Http Error 400 (i.e. not getting a failure badge if this error occurs) ?

Comment: GitHub actions looks like it has support for including/excluding specific folders. Maybe you can trigger the PyPI upload only when your `src/` directory is updated in master? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-paths

Comment: Most CI/CD pipelines I know are written so that they attempt to upload to PyPI only when a git tag is pushed to the repository. There are plenty of tutorials around showing how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @sinoroc, seems suitable to publish on new tag.

```
---
name: pypi_publish
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '**'
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build and publish to pypi
        uses: JRubics/poetry-publish@v1.16
        with:
          pypi_token: ${{ secrets.PYPI_TOKEN }}
```